# ssh2_exec in php not working

Tags: php, linux, ssh, centos

I am tryin to send a exec command in php to a remote server(aerohive). but the exec command does nothing..

I have my ssh2 extension installed and the authetication is also working fine.

Here is the code :

```
        if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect"))
        die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

    if (!($con = ssh2_connect("myipadresherenotshowingtoyouguys", 22))) {
        echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
    } else {
        // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
        if (!ssh2_auth_password($con, "blablabla", "blablabla!")) {
            echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
        } else {
            // allright, we're in!
            echo "okay: logged in...\n";

            // execute a command
            $command = 'ssid "Wentzo test2" hide-ssid';
            if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $command))) {
                echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
            } else {

                $stream2 = ssh2_exec($con, $command_save);
                // collect returning data from command
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $data = "";
                while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
                    $data .= $buf;
                }

                fclose($stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting and show us the error message?

Comment: No errors are given! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file php.ini if it does disabled the function `disable_functions`